# where is Ubuntu terminal config file located

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, xfce4

I'm looking for the config of file for xfce4 Terminal on Ubuntu.

I need to add a command there, An example of an existing command would be ctrl+shift+t to open a new tab.

Comment: Do you mean "terminal emulator" in a desktop environment? What is your desktop environment? Is it Gnome? I believe Gnome uses `gnome-terminal` by default. Is the question about `gnome-terminal`? Please [edit] the question and clarify.

Comment: turns out it's the  xfce4 terminal. 
i need to change the shortcut to switch between tabs

Answer (score 0):

Found it under

~/.config/xfce4/terminal/accels.scm

Docs :

https://docs.xfce.org/faq#how_can_i_see_a_list_of_all_the_shortcut_keys